# Positioning two separate canvases, how?

Tags: css, position, html5-canvas

Why is this code showing the canvases at the same position? So I mean they appear on the top of each other in the sense that if the monitor is the plane(x,y) then 'top' would mean direction z-axis. That's not what I would like to have.

I would like to have the second one below the first one, regarding the y-axis. Could you help please?

```
<body>
    <div id="container1">
        <canvas id="canvas1" width="200" height="200">Get a new browser!</canvas>
        <script>
            var canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas1');
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

            var img = new Image();
            img.src = "pic.jpg";

            img.onload = function(){
                console.log("Loaded img...")
                context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            }
        </script>
    </div>
    <div id="container2">
        <canvas id="canvas2" width="200" height="200">Get a new browser!</canvas>
        <script>
            var canvas2 = document.getElementById('canvas2');
            var context2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');
            context2.fillStyle="red";
            context2.fillRect(21, 21, 100, 100);
        </script>
    </div>
</body>
```

and the css:

```
#container1{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#container2{
    position: absolute;
    top: 200;
    left: 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand that you want #container2 under #container1 then you either move #container2 above #container1 in html or you can set its CSS z-index to a negative number.  `#container2{z-index:-5;}`

Comment: Hi markE, no, I mean 'under' regarding the y-axis. So because both canvases are sized 200x200 and in CSS I gave top:0 and top:200 the second canvas should be under the first. But it isn't. :/

Comment: From your code the absolute containers are relative to the window since no other relative element has been created. Perhaps wrap #container1 & #container2 in a div with position:relative?

Comment: Yes, it solved it! Thank you mate!